# How to access 2 User Controls at a time?(1 from another)

Tags: c#, winforms, popup

I have made 2 user controls. First one contains a textbox and a button. In the second one there is a panel and a repeater control is used. Now when I am writing in the textbox 2nd control will open as a popup and and after focusing to textbox I am unable to write. I have searched a lot about this but nothing works.

```
CustomPopup customPopup;
Popup popup;
popup = new Popup(customPopup = new CustomPopup());

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    popup.Width = Width;
    popup.Show(this);
    popup.AutoClose = false;
}
```

In this way I am opening the popup from the textbox text changed event.

Comment: You mean the popup should appear while typing but user should be allowed to keep typing in the textbox?

Comment: yes. And in the keydown the access should to to the popup.

Comment: but this is a user control

Comment: Oops I confused with your question since it contains "forms"

Comment: please the the link below [Image Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEYto-2a9r3QlJXOV80NkVaaWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So after the popup appears you are unable to type in anything in your textbox field even after clicking there?

Comment: yes that's  the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this textbox event.

```
 private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

this event call whenever textbox get focus